# Convert kerberos ticket to get Azure AD access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

We have on-premise app which works on LDAP and supports WIA , inside that app we are trying to embedded BOT which supports modern authentication OAuth specification. We want when Users access the BOT using from on-prem app, ti should silently authenticate the user.

But how that conversion will happen I am not sure If there is any specification available for that.

Also PRT available not sure If that may help here as machine are Azure AD hybrid joined?

Comment: [SSO is available](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/azuread-join-sso#what-you-get) for the WIA supporting app for joined and hybrid scenarios. What type of bot is this? Do you want to authenticate users to the bot or authenticate it as an application? In the latter case you can use [client credentials](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow). For user accounts take a look to [Request a token using Web Account Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager#request-a-toke

Comment: it is BOT who queries data from Graph API and I wanted to authentication user to the bot using current tokens in the cache when user logs in to the system in the domain-joined machine. PRT is available however not sure how I could use that to authentication BOT who accepts Jwt tokens only.